# boto connection works locally and in heroku python shell but fails in webapp

Tags: python, heroku, flask, boto

I'm not sure how to diagnose this further. Heroku's evns are configured properly. Everything worked on my local machine line a charm. In production i get a internal server error when i try to use this functionality.

I booked up a live shell and everything worked fine there to:

```
In [5]: s3conn = boto.connect_s3(app.config["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],app.config["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])

In [6]: s3conn
Out[6]: S3Connection:s3.amazonaws.com

In [7]: bucket = s3conn.get_bucket(app.config["S3_BUCKET"])

In [8]: bucket
Out[8]: <Bucket: petalbucket>

In [10]: key = bucket.get_key('AGRAPH')

In [11]: key

In [12]: type(key)
Out[12]: NoneType



In [14]: key = bucket.get_key('charts/AGRAPH')

In [15]: key
Out[15]: <Key: petalbucket,charts/AGRAPH>

In [16]: seconds = 60*5

In [17]: url = key.generate_url(expires_in=seconds)

In [18]: url
Out[18]: 'https://petalbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/charts/AGRAPH?Signature=VL9Q9r0Q%2F5UbZDhW%2F%2BeUYFezSGU%3D&Expires=1357251512&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJBEQAKKMVPGYYNRA'
```

code:

```
 def download_s3(file_title):
        s3conn = boto.connect_s3(app.config["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],app.config["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])
        bucket = s3conn.get_bucket(app.config["S3_BUCKET"])
        key = bucket.get_key(file_title)
        seconds = 60*5
        url = key.generate_url(expires_in=seconds)
        return url
```

heroku logs:

```
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 563, in __call__
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = application(environ, _start_response)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-01-03 22:21:05 [7] [ERROR] Error handling request
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 105, in handle_request
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic/api/object_wrapper.py", line 220, in __call__
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._nr_instance, args, kwargs)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 485, in __call__
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._nr_next_object(environ, start_response)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._nr_instance, args, kwargs)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic/api/object_wrapper.py", line 220, in __call__
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._nr_instance, args, kwargs)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 496, in decorated_view
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/petalapp/views.py", line 135, in add_pci_form
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'generate_url'
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/petalapp/aws/tools.py", line 58, in download_s3
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     url = key.generate_url(expires_in=seconds)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic/api/function_trace.py", line 81, in literal_wrapper
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     url =download_s3(in_file + title)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic/api/pre_function.py", line 14, in wrapper
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic/api/object_wrapper.py", line 220, in __call__
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic/api/function_trace.py", line 81, in literal_wrapper
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic/api/object_wrapper.py", line 220, in __call__
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._nr_instance, args, kwargs)
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.9.0.21/newrelic/api/transaction_name.py", line 51, in literal_wrapper
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
2013-01-03T22:21:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
```

My hunch is i'm not understanding something about boto's interaction with heroku. Or haven't set something correctly but i can't see what that could be from this information.

Comment: Did you check your requirements.txt for boto as a dependency?

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral it is. i cleaned up the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack suggests `bucket.get_key(file_title)` returns `None` which is the exact same response you get above when you've typed the wrong file name (i.e. when you look for 'AGRAPH' instead of 'charts/AGRAPH')

What is `file_title` set to? is it correct? I'd suggest some debugging to get the value of that.

Comment: I had a ENV variable slightly wrong and so the file_title was off.